# Bash : What is the best practice syntax for conditional expressions and (pseudo)boolean variables

Tags: bash, boolean, conditional-statements, operators

I read many answers to specific uses of boolean or conditional syntax in bash, but none qualified as the best practice many would need (if you haven't I suggest you read those questions before to proceed with this one: search for bash boolean variables and conditional expressions and read the top five).

The difficulty is bash do not have one but many inconsistent, contradictory and counter-intuitive syntax for this, well reflected in contradictory answers in SE.

Goal: knowing that bash has no boolean types, but conditional statement, operators, status codes and functions, to identify the best syntax for widespread use of logical calculus and execution conditional control within a bash script. Widespread means usable across conditional control commands and variables and operators.

The best practice should IMO meet all these requirements, in order of highest importance :

1. concise if, while, for statements and ternary operator ?:
2. concise assignment and invocation of variables with boolean value
3. concise boolean calculus operators or, and, not, and parentheses with command return status codes and variables

examples of competing syntax :

1. statements:  `if [[`  `if [` `if command` `if $variable`
2. assignments: `t=true` `t=1` `t=$(true)` `t=''` `t=0`
3. operators: `[ true -a false ]` `( true && false )` `(( true * false ))`

So, what would be the best syntax to use, e.g. for this practical example but elsewhere too:

```
 boolresutl1=if commandA or ( $numvarB > $numvarC ) then true
 boolresult2=commandD
 boolresult3=whatever

 if boolresult1 or boolresult2 and not boolresult3 then blabla
```

Best answer would also demonstrate how working alternatives to the proposed best practice would be too verbose.

EDIT: here is a snippet of code that works but still could gain in clarity and conciseness.

The logics goal is to set a variable keepFILE based on a set of time conditions on the file modification date, and file retention policy on Yearly, Quarterly, Monthly, Weekly and Daily. And delete files not meeting that condition.
My key design choice for the script was the value for a true condition, between NULL (satisfying if $var but not  [[ $var ]]), or "true" (satisfying [[ $var ]] but not if $var).

```
# date -d @12345 (seconds since epoch)  formats:  +%u (7= Sunday)  +%d (01= 1st dom) +%m (01=Jan) 
    unset isY isQ isM isW
# is beg of Week ?
[[ "$(date -d @$filedatesecs +%u)" =  7 ]] && isW=true
# is beg of Month ?
[[ "$(date -d @$filedatesecs +%d)" = 01 ]] && isM=true
# is beg of Quarter ?
[[ $isM && $(date -d @$filedatesecs +%m) =~ ^(01|04|07|10)$  ]] && isQ=true
# is beg of Year ?  
[[ $isM &&  "$(date -d @$filedatesecs +%m)" = 01 ]] && isY=true


unset keepD keepW keepM keepQ keepY keepFILE
    [[ $fileagedays -le $maxdaysD ]] && keepD=true
    [[ $fileagedays -le $maxdaysW ]] && [[  $isW ]] && keepW=true
    [[ $fileagedays -le $maxdaysM ]] && [[  $isM ]] && keepM=true
    [[ $fileagedays -le $maxdaysQ ]] && [[  $isQ ]] && keepQ=true
    [[ $fileagedays -le $maxdaysY ]] && [[  $isY ]] && keepY=true
    [[ $keepD || $keepW || $keepM || $keepQ || $keepY ]] && keepFILE=true
```

Comment: Having read the question twice, I really didn't understand what's being asked here. bash is an implementation of [POSIX sh](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) with a handful of extensions and that's that. If you have suggestions on how to improve the standard, refer to [POSIX bug list](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view_all_bug_page.php), if you have feature requests for bash, post it to [bug-bash mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/bug-bash)

Comment: There is also [modernish project](https://github.com/modernish/modernish), which claims to provide *modern* extensions to POSIX shells. [tag:zsh] could also be deemed a modern derivation of sh I guess, or if you think unix shells are not for you, you can take a look at [tag:fish]

Comment: However, I see no point in supporting complex boolean operations in a *shell scripting language*. There are many scripting languages with lots of features out there, such as [tag:python], [tag:perl], [tag:awk], [tag:tcl], [tag:lua], etc. etc.

Comment: I need "combined" conditions because I wrote a backup/archiving script handling date related logics, and bash was the choice because it's widespread on distros vanilla installs. I finally used syntax very close to @chepner suggestions, it took me a day to bump into and work around the language redundancies and contradictions. Hence my question for a best standard and productive way of handling combined conditions in future work. I already gave up my initial goal of code conciseness. Here is my best pick of contradictions: (cond=) if $cond and if [[ $cond ]]  give the opposite result.

Comment: Most languages make a definite arbitrary choice of what are the TRUE and FALSE values, that can be used consistently in the IF like statements. In bash, an empty variable is evaluated as TRUE in if $var and as FALSE in if [[ $var ]] . !

Comment: Because shell is an old language that developed strangely. Shell is not meant to replace a programming language. Yes `[[ "string" ]]` checks if the length of string is not empty, this is what it does. If you want to check if a string is equal to "true", you should `[[ $var = "true" ]]`. If you want to execute a program `true` and check it's return value, you can do `if $var`. The examples do distinct and unrelated things. Read the documentation about what it does, don't guess it. Shell does not have a boolean type - shell has only strings.

Comment: `examples of competing syntax` - you mentioned bash specific syntax ie. `[[` and `((`, but there are other shells with their specific syntax. Yes, each person that invents a shell tries to add something that will help people. Sometimes people start using it, sometimes not. You ask about "best syntax" - best in what way? Readability? Portability? Execution speed? Sometimes things end up in the shell because it's easier to port it from other shells. So bash has `readarray` and `mapfile`. And `declare` and `typeset`. And `-le` inside `[[` - so that you could easily port `[` to `[[`.

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudocode

```
# boolresutl1=if commandA or ( $boolvarB > $boolvarC ) then true
# boolresult2=commandD
# boolresult3=whatever

# if boolresult1 or boolresult2 and not boolresult3 then blabla
```

would be best written with something like

```
# Assuming `boolVarB` and `$boolvarC` are integer-valued.
if commandA || [ "$boolvarB" -gt "$boolvarC" ] || commandD && ! whatever; then
    blabla
fi
```

Note that `||` and `&&` have equal precedence; `whatever` only runs if `commandA` and  `[` both fail and `commandD` succeeds. If you need to group things, use `{ ... ; }`, e.g.,

```
# Only run commandC if commandA fails and commandB succeeds,
# not when either commandA or commandB succeeds.
if commandA || { commandB && commandC; }; then
```

---

If for whatever reason you need to remember exit statuses for later use, immediately save the result of `$?`:

```
commandA || [ "$boolvarB" -gt "$boolvarC" ]
result1=$?
commandD
result2=$?
whatever
result3=$?

...

if [ "$result1" -eq 0 ] || [ "$result2" -eq 0 ] || commandD && [ "$result3" -ne 0 ]; then
   blablabla
fi
```

---

A few comments:

1. `t=$(true)` is exactly equivalent to `t=`, except it takes longer, because `true` doesn't write anything to standard output.
2. The `-a` and `-o` operators are obsolete and non-standard. Never use them; replace `[ x -a y ]` with `[ x ] && [ y ]`, and `[ x -o y ]` with `[ x ] || [ y ]`.
3. `(( true * false ))` (for appropriately integer-valued variables) is just unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: Any reason why you do not mention [[ ]] and use [ ] ? The former is said to be the way to go. See the code  ended up with in my last edit.

Comment: Also, [[ allowed me to use the string matching operator =~ so I went for [[ and removed all usage of [ ] to avoid messing with two standards in the script. =~ was necessary due to the nasty silent interpretation of 08 as octal by bash breaking my date comparisons (inline forcing interpretation as decimal failed so I gave it up).

Comment: Let me add @chepner that your answer was understanding, helpful and insightful, thank  you, and I upvoted it although it does not appear yet, cause I am a brand new registered user of SE (while being a long time unregistered reader). I fail to understand why this same question would bring up both useful answers like yours and silly error-filled comments and downvotes like the above one. Do I need to call for upvotes of my question to be able to influence that strange platform behavior ? Really puzzling.

Comment: The question is fairly broad and I'm not sure there is an objective answer to most of it. I tried, but I may have only succeeded in a simplified opinion.